# Understanding .features method of topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm still pretty new to D3 and I'm working through a few online examples to develop a better understanding.

Looking at [this](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4060606) example, I'm having a hard time figuring out the code on line 33 of the index file is doing:

```
.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
```

If I have this right, I believe topojson.feature() converts the topojson file into geojson and accepts arguments for the data (us) and the object of interest (counties)...?

But what does the last method, `.features` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.features` is not a method, that's just a property of the GeoJSON object. It is created by `topojson.feature` (which, by the way, is a real method).

According to the [GeoJSON specs](https://github.com/geojson/geojson-spec/blob/master/geojson-spec-draft.rst#feature-collection-objects),

> **2.3. Feature Collection Objects**
>
> A GeoJSON object with the type "FeatureCollection" is a feature collection object.
>
> An object of type "FeatureCollection" must have a member with the name "features". The value corresponding to "features" is an array. Each element in the array is a feature object as defined above.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. `.feature` is the topojson method that creates the GeoJSON object, whereas `.features` accesses the features property of that newly created object. Thank you!